# Page factory model Selenium Java - WebElement List returns empty list whereas Page object returns size

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

```
Page object model and using driver.find elements

int noOfLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[@class='_78mc9p']")).size();
        System.out.println(noOfLinks);

Prints the size as "6" which is expected
```

whereas in page factory I use findby and pass the same xpath and it return size as zero.

```
Pagefactory and using findBy
    @FindBy(xpath = "//p[@class='_78mc9p']")
    public List<WebElement> noOfLinks;

Page factory method
 public int countLinks(){
     return noOfLinks.size();
   }

Test
        ObjName.countLinks();
        System.out.println(ObjName.countLinks());
```

Compared to page object model to Page factory - the same xpath isnt returning the value. Does FindBy work different?

Comment: how you are passing driver instance? also instead of list, just try find element to see what exception it will throw

Comment: I passed driver through page factory constructor.'public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
  this.driver= driver;
  PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
  
 }'  I tried with find element too and still got size as 0.